# Concat several dataframes but with index order with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have several dataframes with datetime as indexes.

```
df1
index        col1   col2

2022-01-01    5      20
2022-01-01    3      15


df2
index        col1   col2
    
2022-01-02    4      20
2022-01-02    7      15


df2
index        col1   col2
        
2022-01-03    45      2
2022-01-03    96      7
```

but when I concat several dfs with the following code:

```
PATH_sbl = r'../data-cleaned/'
filenames = glob.glob(PATH_sbl + "/*.csv")

dfs = []
for filename in filenames:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

df_ts = pd.concat(dfs)
df_ts = df_ts.set_index('fecha')
```

I get the following dataframe:

```
index        col1   col2

2022-01-01    5      20
2022-01-01    3      15
2022-01-03    45      2
2022-01-03    96      7
2022-01-02    4      20
2022-01-02    7      15
```

the final dataframe do not have the index in order (according the datetime index).

I would like to have the index in order:

```
index        col1   col2
    
2022-01-01    5      20
2022-01-01    3      15
2022-01-02    4      20
2022-01-02    7      15
2022-01-03    45      2
2022-01-03    96      7
```

Answer (score 0):

From pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=[100, 29, 234, 1, 150],
                  columns=['A'])
df.sort_index()
     A
1    4
29   2
100  1
150  5
234  3
```